# How to resolve: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random-forest, ensemble-learning

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
import keras.backend as K
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import pandas as pd

class CustomThreshold(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """ Custom threshold wrapper for binary classification"""
    def __init__(self, base, threshold=0.5):
        self.base = base
        self.threshold = threshold
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base.fit(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        return (self.base.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] > self.threshold).astype(int)

dataset_clinical = np.genfromtxt("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/BreastCancer-master/Data/stacked_metadata.csv",delimiter=",")
X = dataset_clinical[:,0:450]
Y = dataset_clinical[:,450]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=1)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10).fit(X,Y) 
clf = [CustomThreshold(rf, threshold) for threshold in [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]]

for model in clf:
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, model.predict(X_test)))
for model in clf:
    print(confusion_matrix(Y, model.predict(X)))
```

*The traceback displays the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "RF.py", line 33, in 
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10).fit(X,Y)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 328, in fit
X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 576, in _validate_data
X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 968, in check_X_y estimator=estimator,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 792, in check_array_assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 116, in _assert_all_finite type_err, msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
*

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say check your dataset for missing values, outliers etc.

A big part of any ML model is data exploration and preprocessing. I found a guide for that, for beginners. Pandas: https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-exploration-using-pandas-only-beginner-a0a52eb723d5